# Rendering to Home Page when a Slug is not available (DJANGO)

Tags: python, django

I have created a webpage where an admin can create random pages via admin page using slug adding the name into the slug field. What I am trying to do is if a user tries to render to random page it should to go a "404" page.

Model

```
class CustomPage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    displayOnFooter = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('custom-page', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py

```
def custom_page(request, slug):
    context = {
        'all': CustomPage.objects.filter(slug=slug),
        'toBePublished': CustomPage.objects.all()
    }
    all_query = CustomPage.objects.all()
    count = 0;
    for i in all_query:
        if i.slug == slug:
            return render(request, 'member/custom_page.html', context)
        elif count < len(all_query):
            count += 1;
        else:
            return render(request, 'member/home.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
    path('register/', views.register, name='member-register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='member/login.html'), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='member/logout.html'), name = 'logout'),
    path('forgot-password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='member/forgot-password.html'), name = 'member-forgot-password'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name = 'profile'),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='member/login.html')),
    path('groups/', views.groups, name='member-group'),
    path('groups/<slug:slug>/', views.groups_detail, name='member-group-detail'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.custom_page, name='custom-page'),
```

When I add a random string myself at the end so for example:

http://127.0.0.1/dasada/

I get a

**ValueError at /dasada/
The view member.views.custom_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.**

Thanks
Onur

Comment: Why are you using `count`? What happens is that your view loop ends without ever selecting the branches that return a response, so it returns None. You have to return a response in all cases. Also the for loop does not need to count anything.

Comment: Would be able to share the correct code? I have tried some but didnt work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, all possible exit paths from the view return a response.
It is only different from the default response, when you match the slug for a custom page:

```
def custom_page(request, slug):
    context = {
        'all': CustomPage.objects.filter(slug=slug),
        'toBePublished': CustomPage.objects.all()
    }
    custom_pages = CustomPage.objects.all()
    for page in custom_pages:
        if page.slug == slug:
            return render(request, 'member/custom_page.html', context)
    # ends the search with no match
    return render(request, 'member/home.html',context)
```